# Repeat entire group 0 or more times (one or more words separated by +'s)

Tags: python, regex, regex-group

I am trying to match words separated with the `+` character as input from a user in python and check if each of the words is in a predetermined list. I am having trouble creating a regular expression to match these words (words are comprised of more than one `A-z` characters). For example, an input string `foo` should match as well as `foo+bar` and `foo+bar+baz` with each of the words (not `+`'s) being captured.

So far, I have tried a few regular expressions but the closest I have got is this:

```
/^([A-z+]+)\+([A-z+]+)$/
```

However, this only matches the case in which there are two words separated with a `+`, I need there to be *one or more* words. My method above would have worked if I could somehow repeat the second group (`\+([A-z+]+)`) zero or more times. So hence my question is: How can I repeat a capturing group zero or more times?

If there is a better way to do what I am doing, please let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could write the pattern as:

```
(?i)[A-Z]+(?:\+[A-Z]+)*$
```

**Explanation**

- `(?i)` Inline modifier for case insensitive
- `[A-Z]+` Match 1+ chars A-Z
- `(?:\+[A-Z]+)*` Optionally repeat matching `+` and again 1+ chars A-Z
- `$` End of string

See a [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/zenvr6/1) for the matches:

For example

```
import re

predeterminedList = ["foo", "bar"]
strings = ["foo", "foo+bar", "foo+bar+baz", "test+abc"]
pattern = r"(?i)[A-Z]+(?:\+[A-Z]+)*$"

for s in strings:
    m = re.match(pattern, s)
    if m:
        words = m.group().split("+")
        intersect = bool(set(words) & set(predeterminedList))
        fmt = ','.join(predeterminedList)
        if intersect:
            print(f"'{s}' contains at least one of '{fmt}'")
        else:
            print(f"'{s}' contains none of '{fmt}'")
```

Another option could be created a dynamic pattern listing the alternatives:

```
(?i)^(?:[A-Z]+\+)*(?:foo|bar)(?:\+[A-Z]+)*$
```

Example

```
import re

predeterminedList = ["foo", "bar"]
strings = ["foo", "foo+bar", "foo+bar+baz", "test+abc"]
pattern = rf"(?i)^(?:[A-Z]+\+)*(?:{'|'.join(predeterminedList)})(?:\+[A-Z]+)*$"

for s in strings:
    m = re.match(pattern, s)
    fmt = ','.join(predeterminedList)
    if m:
        print(f"'{s}' contains at least one of '{fmt}'")
    else:
        print(f"'{s}' contains none of '{fmt}'")
```

Both will output:

```
'foo' contains at least one of 'foo,bar'
'foo+bar' contains at least one of 'foo,bar'
'foo+bar+baz' contains at least one of 'foo,bar'
'test+abc' contains none of 'foo,bar'
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for, thanks for also including the python code (I didn't even ask for it :) but still helped)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend slightly different approach using lookarounds:

Pattern: `(?<=^|\+)(?=foo|baz)[^+]+`

Pattern explanation:

`(?<=^|\+)` - positive lookbehind - assert that preceeding text is neither `^` (beginning of string) or `+` (our 'word delimiter').

`(?=foo|baz)` - positive lookahead - assert that following text match one of words (from predefined list)

`[^+]+` - match one or more characters other from `+`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/U8xGuh/1)